# Initializing a field member in Kotlin that is a function

Tags: kotlin

New to Kotlin, I have seen this code:

```
val myModule : Module = module {
  viewModel { MyViewModel(get()) } 
  single { MyRepository() }
}
```

Looking at the Kotlin docs, it isn't clear to me what the braces mean after "module". Is module a function and the braces are used to initialize the function? If this is true, can you point me to the part in the Kotlin documentation that indicates this? I can't find anything in the docs that shows an example of this. Here is the link:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your example seems like [Koin](https://insert-koin.io/) code.

In a more general sense:
In kotlin when the last parameter of a function is another function ( see [Higher order functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)) you can put it outside the parenthesis, and if it is the only (non optional) parameter you can omit the parenthesis enterily.

In your example `module` `viewModel` and `single` are functions that take another function as their only parameter, this way you can pass the lambda defining this paramter directly without any parenthesis.

Comment: Coming from a Java background, I easily forget that Kotlin rule about being able to place the last parameter outside the paranthesis if it's a function. You're also right about it being code from Koin. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The braces mean that the `module` function receives a lambda as a parameter. http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter